# how can i cache mongodb queries in c#

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, caching, memcached, in-memory

```
Where(Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filterExpression, int page = 1, int pageSize = 100);
Find(FilterDefinition<TDocument> filterExpression);
```

I want to do prepopulation caching based on data access layer query.
I do not want the cache to be deleted in data addition, update and deletion processes. Let it be added to the database and added to the cache. How can I cache based on filterExpression?
Does it make sense to cache the whole table and query on it?
how can i solve this cache problem?